# MVC 1: string value in model is not passed to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I pass to the view some values in the model, including a DateTime variable StrInvoiceDate:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult PaymentDetails(int invoiceID, string invoiceDate, decimal grandTotalPrice)
    {
        PaymentDetailsViewData vd = CreateViewData<PaymentDetailsViewData>();
        vd.InvoiceID = invoiceID;
        vd.StrInvoiceDate = invoiceDate;
        vd.GrandTotalPrice = grandTotalPrice;

        return View(vd);
    }

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<PaymentDetailsViewData>" %>
      <h2><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_PaymentDetails%></h2>


<form id="Payment" method="post">

   <fieldset>
        <legend>Card Details</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Card Type</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <input id="visa" name="CardType" value="1" type="radio" checked />
                    <label class="RadioLabel" for="visa">VISA</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input id="amex" name="CardType" value="2" type="radio" />
                    <label class="RadioLabel" for="amex">AmEx</label>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input id="mastercard" name="CardType" value="3" type="radio" />
                    <label class="RadioLabel" for="mastercard">Mastercard</label>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="CardNumber"><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_CardNumber%></label>
            <input id="CardNumber" name="CardNumber" type="number" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="CardExpirationDate"><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_Expiration%></label>
            <input id="CardExpirationDate" name="CardExpirationDate" type="month" min='<%=System.DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM")%>' required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="SecurityCode"><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_SecurityCode%></label>
            <input id="SecurityCode" name="SecurityCode" type="number" required />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="NameOnCard"><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_NameOnCard%></label>
            <input id="NameOnCard" name="NameOnCard" type="text" placeholder="<%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_NameOnCardHint%>" required />
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
    <button type="submit"><%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_MakePayment%></button>
</fieldset>
```

<%=Resources.Global.Account_Payment_MakePayment%>/button>

Now when I submit the form in that view, StrInvoiceDate is null, though both InvoiceID and GrandTotalPrice is there. Why can this happen?

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult PaymentDetails(PaymentDetailsViewData vd)
    {
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your view code? Are you actually posting the `invoiceDate` field?

Comment: I edited my question. StrInvoiceDate is just a member of my Model class, as well as InvoiceID and GrandTotalPrice.

Comment: Could you provide all of your view code?

Comment: You haven't actually included the markup for the `StrInvoiceDate`.

Comment: It is because it is not used in the view, I just need this data on submit. None of the 3 mentioned fields is displayed in the view.

Comment: So you're not even putting them in hidden fields in your view? How would the form know what to post?

Comment: @DmitriyReznik Since none of them is in the view, they all are assigned to default values - for `int` it is 0, for `decimal` also 0 and for `string` it is `null`. This is how MVC works. If you want to have a value you need to add them to the view, either in visible `input` fields, or in hidden field

Comment: That is what I thought. But then I noticed that the other two fields of the model did actually preserve the values. How can you explain this?

Comment: @MajorByte I thought maybe the form "knows" to post whatever is in the view?

Comment: @DmitriyReznik Would you like to provide a sample of what is not working on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)? You can choose project type MVC and create a sample project. From what I know the values should not be preserved, maybe I missed something

Comment: Has a long time that I don't work with MVC 1, but, I can remember that you must access the FormCollection to retrieve any value posted from the form.

Comment: My model that comes with postback perfectly contains all model fields values... but that one.

Comment: @dotnetom This fiddle thing doesn't work for me. I am trying to return Response.Write() to display what comes in the model, but nothing happens, and I don't know how to step inside of the action method.

Comment: Please update your question with your view. Otherwise virtually nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: How is StrInvoiceDate defined in your ViewModel? What value does the hidden field have in the html/view?

Comment: @MajorByte Sorry for the confusion, originally there was no StrInvoiceData hidden field. I added it later to make it work, and with it everything works. I just wonder what the difference is between this model field (which is a string) and other two fields, that they don't need to be stored in a hidden field. I remove the hidden field from the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Unless you are doing something with TempData I can only guess that you are actively setting InvoiceID and GrandTotalPrice somewhere yourself. But in the state your question is in, I think nobody will be able to answer your question, i.e. what happens in CreateViewModel, are you using any custom model binders, how does your PaymentDetailsViewData look like etc. etc. etc.